# How to create a new column from existing two columns but omitting NAs rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that a portion of it looks like this:

```
Domain <- c(rep("Bacteria",3),rep("Archaea", 2))
Phylum <- c("Proteobacteria","Cyanobacteria","Planctomycetota", "Thermoplasmatota", "Thermoplasmatota")
Class <- c("Alphaproteobacteria","Cyanobacteriia","Phycisphaerae","Poseidoniia_A",NA)
Order <- c("Sphingomonadales", NA, "Phycisphaerales", "Poseidoniales", NA)
Family <- c("Emcibacteraceae", NA, NA, "Poseidonia", NA)
Genus <- c("UBA4441", NA,NA,NA,NA)
Species <- c("UBA4441 sp", NA,NA,NA,NA)


demo_table <- data.frame(Domain, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, Genus, Species)
```

The point here is I want to create a new column called "assignation" that consist in the merge of the last two columns that contain non NA values row by row and that the values are separated by a space.

This is the expected output:

| Domain | Phylum | Class | Order | Family | Genus | Species | assignation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bacteria | Proteobacteria | Alphaproteobacteria | Sphingomonadales | Emcibacteraceae | UBA4441 | UBA4441 sp | UBA4441 UBA4441 sp |
| Bacteria | Cyanobacteria | Cyanobacteriia | NA | NA | NA | NA | Cyanobacteria Cyanobacteriia |
| Bacteria | Planctomycetota | Phycisphaerae | Phycisphaerales | NA | NA | NA | Phycisphaerae Phycisphaerales |
| Archaea | Thermoplasmatota | Poseidoniia_A | Poseidoniales | Poseidonia | NA | NA | Poseidoniales Poseidonia |
| Archaea | Thermoplasmatota | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | Archaea Thermoplasmatota |

I Think that `paste()` may work on this case but not sure how to implement it so I can get the above mentioned expected output data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `base R` - loop over the rows, remove the NA with `na.omit`, get the last two elements `tail` with `n = 2` and `paste`

```
demo_table$assignation <- apply(demo_table, 1, 
   function(x) paste(tail(na.omit(x), 2), collapse = " "))
```

-output

```
demo_table$assignation
[1] "UBA4441 UBA4441 sp"            "Cyanobacteria Cyanobacteriia"  "Phycisphaerae Phycisphaerales" "Poseidoniales Poseidonia"     
[5] "Archaea Thermoplasmatota"
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we may also use `unite` and remove the  `NA` with `na.rm = TRUE`, then extract the last two words

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
demo_table %>% 
  unite(assignation, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(assignation = str_replace(assignation,     
     ".*_([^_]+)_([^_]+)$", "\\1 \\2")) %>% 
  relocate(assignation, .after =last_col())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go for a `tidyverse` approach, you just need to use `rowwise` + `c_across`. I think is it also nice to transform this operation in a function, in case you need to use later or even change the behavior of it.

### Code

```
library(dplyr)

select_last <- function(x, n = 2){paste(tail(na.omit(x),n = n),collapse = " ")}

demo_table %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(assignation  = select_last(c_across()))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Rowwise: 
  Domain  Phylum      Class        Order       Family     Genus Species  assignation        
  <chr>   <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <chr>    <chr>              
1 Bacter~ Proteobact~ Alphaproteo~ Sphingomon~ Emcibacte~ UBA4~ UBA4441~ UBA4441 UBA4441 sp 
2 Bacter~ Cyanobacte~ Cyanobacter~ NA          NA         NA    NA       Cyanobacteria Cyan~
3 Bacter~ Planctomyc~ Phycisphaer~ Phycisphae~ NA         NA    NA       Phycisphaerae Phyc~
4 Archaea Thermoplas~ Poseidoniia~ Poseidonia~ Poseidonia NA    NA       Poseidoniales Pose~
5 Archaea Thermoplas~ NA           NA          NA         NA    NA       Archaea Thermoplas~
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `dplyr` combined with `tidyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
demo_table %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  arrange(-row_number(), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(assignation = paste(value[1], value[2], sep = "\n")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(assignation) %>% 
  bind_cols(demo_table) %>% 
  View()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another efficient approach, that concatenates columns "on the fly", is a simple loop over the columns of the 'data.frame':

```
# keep track of rows whose last 2 non missing items have been located
completed = logical(nrow(demo_table)) 

assignation = character(nrow(demo_table))
for(j in ncol(demo_table):2) {  # search from last column
  j1 = demo_table[[j - 1L]]
  j2 = demo_table[[j]]
  nona = !is.na(j1) & !is.na(j2) & !completed  # which columns to concatenate
  assignation[nona] = paste(j1[nona], j2[nona], sep = " ")
  completed[nona] = TRUE
}

assignation  
#[1] "UBA4441 UBA4441 sp"            "Cyanobacteria Cyanobacteriia"  "Phycisphaerae Phycisphaerales"
#[4] "Poseidoniales Poseidonia"      "Archaea Thermoplasmatota"
```